# Why can't I change mode with nested FormView?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, formview

The short version is that I have nested `FormViews`.  I would like the child FormView to only change modes when the parent does so as well, so I handle the ParentFV.ModeChanging event and call `ChildFV.ChangeMode` within that...

For some reason, the Child FormView's mode doesn't change... nore does the Child's ModeChanging event appear to get fired...

Why would this not work?

EDIT: I came up with a workaround, hooking the Inserted and Updated events and using the KeepIn*Mode to prevent them from going back too early... setting the mode itself on page_load according to the current DynamicData mode...

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle are you changing the children?  Can we see your code?

Comment: When the event handlers are being called... which I could kind of see it missing the event handler, but it wasn't changing the mode at all either... that part should have worked shouldn't it?